# Skipping hidden rows - Outlook recipient table

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have worked alot of time on this code.  The Workbook has a main page control hub to send multiple emails in a sequence out.  After I send the first email to the table of recipiants I record those who respond.  If the recipiant respods then I filter them out before sending the next email.  I am trying to find a way to skip the hidden rows as they contain contacts who do not need to recieve the second email.  I am stumped.

```
Sub Send_seq_two()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TheHub")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables")
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts")
Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim msg As Object
Dim sign As String
Dim I As Integer

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Application.Range("mt").ListObject

Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = tbl.Range.Rows(tbl.Range.Rows.Count).Row


If sh.Range("B2").Value <> "2" Or sh3.Range("K6").Value = "1" Then
MsgBox "check sequence"
End If


For I = 6 To lrow

Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)


    If sh3.Range("H" & I).Value <> "" And sh3.Range("K" & I).Value = "" And sh3.Range("J" & I).Value = "1" And sh.Range("B2").Value = "2" Then

    msg.Display
    sign = msg.HTMLBody

    msg.To = sh3.Range("H" & I).Value
    msg.CC = sh3.Range("I" & I).Value
    msg.Subject = sh.Range("B3").Value
    msg.HTMLBody = "<p><span style='font-size:15px;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;'>Hi " & sh3.Range("D" &     I).Value & ",<br><br>" & sh2.Range("D3").Value & sign
    

    If sh.Range("B4").Value <> "" Then
    msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("B4").Value


    End If

    msg.Send
    
    
    sh.Range("C14").Value = Date
    sh3.Range("K" & I).Value = "1"
    



End If

Next I

End Sub
```

I have unsuccessfuly tried using the hidden row property but I think I am applying it incorrectly.  I only want to skip the hidden rows as they are emails I do not want going out.  I do not want to delete them entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you can modify below code as your requirements

```
dim i as Range, emailRng as Range, r as Long
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts")

' to figure out only visible cells after applying filter
set emailRng = sh3.Range("H1:H" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

for each i in emailRng
    r = i.row
    msg.To = sh3.Range("H" & r).Value
    msg.CC = sh3.Range("I" & r).Value
Next
```

Comment: I was able to use this to modify the code.  I got it to work per your suggestion.  Thank you so much.